# .net Web Api 2 File Upload

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api2

I trying to upload the file using web api and i follow the example in the site:

http://www.strathweb.com/2012/08/a-guide-to-asynchronous-file-uploads-in-asp-net-web-api-rtm/

It works great... but i don't want to override the file if file exists. Basically if the file already exists i want to save the file with a time stamp.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Minutes after I post the question I figure out. Here is the answer, is pretty simple... i just had a dumb moment.

```
  public class CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider : MultipartFormDataStreamProvider
{
    private readonly string _rootDirectory = 'filesRoot';
    public CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(string path) : base(path)
    {
    }

    public override string GetLocalFileName(HttpContentHeaders headers)
    {
        var filename = headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
        if (File.Exists(_rootDirectory + filename))
        {
            var fName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(_rootDirectory + filename);
            var extension = Path.GetExtension(_rootDirectory + filename); 
            return fName + '_' + DateTime.Now.Ticks + extension;
        }
        else
            return filename;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was about to add code but it looks like you got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [File.Exisits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx) to test if file already exist and if it does use [DateTime.Now.Ticks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx) to append a timestamp